# Sample N edges that are not in adjacency list

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume I have a pandas dataframe like the following one:

```
   user_id  item_id
0   697226     2888
1   188374     5718
2   840786     2498
3   408107      265
4   108218     6081
```

A row can be think as a relation between an user and an item. So I would like to sample N relations that do not exist on my dataframe.

I am following a greedy approach right now:

```
pairs = set([(row.user_id, row.item_id) for i, row in dataset.iterrows()])

i = 0
while i <= train_samples:
    amigo = random.randint(0, n_amigos)
    item = random.randint(0, n_clothes)

    if (amigo, item) not in pairs:
        pairs.add((amigo, item))
        i +=1
        dataset.loc[train_samples+i] = [amigo, item]
```

But I am not very proud of it. Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to add a number of rows populated by random numbers?

Comment: Yes, but that do not exist in the dataframe already

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` to create all the combinaisons possible in a new dataframe and then `drop` the one already existing in `df`. Then `reset_index` to get the values as columns:

```
df_combi = (pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.user_id,df.item_id], 
                                                          names=['user_id','item_id']))
              .drop(df.set_index(['user_id','item_id']).index).reset_index())
```

and with you input, you get for `df_combi.head()`:

```
   user_id  item_id
0   697226     5718
1   697226     2498
2   697226      265
3   697226     6081
4   188374     2888
```

Now if you want N rows in this dataframe, you can use `sample`:

```
N = 4
print (df_combi.sample(N))
Out[109]: 
    user_id  item_id
4    188374     2888
15   408107     6081
1    697226     2498
8    840786     2888
```

so to add it to you previous dataframe you can use `pd.concat` do:

```
df = pd.concat([df,df_combi.sample(N)],ignore_index=True)
```

and you get for `df`:

```
    user_id  item_id
0    697226     2888
1    188374     5718
2    840786     2498
3    408107      265
4    108218     6081
5    408107     6081
6    188374     2498
7    840786     2888
8    697226     6081
```

where row index 5 to 8 are the couples not existing in your orignal dataframe

Comment: Your method works but creating the whole combinations set is too heavy when dealing with big datasets.

Comment: @m33n what are the dimension of your data? also can you have already several time the same user with different item?

Comment: I have more than 2 million rows. Yes, you can, but it would be good to balance it as much as possible.

Comment: @m33n it make sense with 2M it will be huge. At least, `unique` should be added when creating the Multiindex such as `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.user_id.unique(),df.item_id.unique()], names=['user_id','item_id'])` but even if you 50K unique user and 50K unique item, it will be big

Comment: @m33n and what do you mean by "balance"? if user 1 has 4 items and user 2 only 2, you would like to add more user 2 that user 1?